# initctl does not list, start job

Tags: systemd, upstart

Given file `/etc/init/somejob.conf` defined as:

```
 # somejob - testing job init
 description "start or stop test"

 script
         $(readlink -f $(which echo)) hey
 end script
```

Does not appear with `initctl list` (also after reboot) and is not callable with `start`:

```
 CANTANDO init # init-checkconf -d /etc/init/somejob.conf 
 DEBUG: upstart_path=/sbin/upstart
 DEBUG: initctl_path=/sbin/initctl
 DEBUG: Setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/tmp/init-checkconf.vsmNHz1rYD'
 DEBUG: Unsetting UPSTART_SESSION (unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1734)
 DEBUG: confdir=/tmp/init-checkconf.QM6a9aX0XM
 DEBUG: file=/etc/init/somejob.conf
 DEBUG: job=somejob
 DEBUG: upstart_out=/tmp/init-checkconf-upstart-output.ja4gR1vtyW
 DEBUG: upstart_cmd=/sbin/upstart --user --no-dbus --no-startup-event --verbose --confdir /tmp/init-checkconf.QM6a9aX0XM
 DEBUG: Upstart pid=3573
 DEBUG: Waiting for Upstart to initialise (attempt 1)
 DEBUG: Joining Upstart session 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/0/3573'
 DEBUG: Waiting for Upstart to initialise (attempt 2)
 DEBUG: Secondary Upstart (/sbin/upstart --user --no-dbus --no-startup-event --verbose --confdir /tmp/init-checkconf.QM6a9aX0XM) running with PID 3573
 File /etc/init/somejob.conf: syntax ok
 DEBUG: Restoring XDG_RUNTIME_DIR to '/run/user/1000'
 DEBUG: Restoring UPSTART_SESSION to 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1734'
 DEBUG: Stopping secondary Upstart (running with PID 3573)
 CANTANDO init # initctl reload-configuration
 CANTANDO init # initctl list | grep some
 CANTANDO init # start somejob
 start: Unknown job: somejob
 CANTANDO init # initctl start somejob
 initctl: Unknown job: somejob
```

`syslog` shows nothing.

Reading [Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) and the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/init) I can't find that  additional steps are required to installing a service using **Upstart** other than adding file `/etc/init/servicename.conf`. Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

*Using Ubuntu 16.04, upstart 1.13.2*

Comment: Just to close off possibly red herring answers: This is 16.04 that you have _switched from systemd back to upstart_, yes? This needs to be explicitly stated.

Comment: Oh wow, 16.04 doesn't use upstart by default anymore? That would be the explanation, then ...

Comment: But when I involke `initctl list` I still get a list of services. This list is still compiled with data from somewhere, which I would assume would be the dir structure?